# Communicating between different module's component function

Tags: angular, module, components

I have two-component ComponentA and ComponentB. These two-component are declared in different modules. Now I want ComponentA function to be called from ComponentB. This two-component don't have parent-child relations.

```
export class ComponentA{
 randomfun(){
 console.log('random function entered');
 }
}
```

```
constructor(private comA: ComponentA){}
export class ComponentB{
// calling component A function
comA.randomfun();
}
```

This code has resulted in StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ComponentB -> ComponentA]

Comment: use a service to comunicate between the components: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service (in subscribe function, call the function of the component). Ah! it's indifferent in witch module are defined each one

Comment: I didn't get the last sentence.

Comment: sorry my English, I want to say that the components can be in different modules or not (it's the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `shared singleton service`:

```
  @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class SharedService {
        private _invokeSource: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
        public invokeObservable: Observable<void> = this._invokeSource.asObservable();
        public invoke(): void {
            this._invokeSource.next();
    }
    }
```

component A:

[...] `this.sharedService.invoke();`

component B:

[...]

```
private _subscription: Subscription;
this._subscription = this.sharedService.invokeObservable.subscribe(() => this.randomfun())
```

Additionally, to avoid memory leaks, you should unsubscribe to the custom observable during `ngOnDestroy()`:

```
public ngOnDestroy(){
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-service-invoke

Note that if the component you are trying to invoke the method on is not loaded in dom, this will not work. In that case you will have to create an instance of the component class and invoke the method on that (Although I wouldn't recommend doing this, ever).

Comment: randomfun does not exist on type 'ComponentB'. Could you provide any working demo

Comment: `randomfun()` is whatever method you're trying to invoke obviously. I added an elaborate demo to show the approach.